# How to limit the memory usage in subprocess and check it when out of memory on Linux

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

I use the `setrlimit` API to limit the sub-process resources and check it on the parent process.

When the sub-process exceed the memory limit, it will be terminated by a `SIGSEV` signal, but I have some other reasons also cause the `SIGSEV` signal, so I can't judge whether the sub-process exceeded the memory limit.

Is there a way to know whether the sub-process exceed the memory limit?

Comment: Aren't you using the `setrlimit` function? check the man page of setrlimit, https://linux.die.net/man/2/setrlimit

Comment: You don't need to kill the child pid in POSIX, they will die once they run out of memory.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you don't currently have any crashing bugs (that you know of), but want to learn how to differentiate between (future) crashing bugs and the crashes that happens when a limit is reached. Is that correct?

Comment: Yeah,it's correct.the SIGSEV signal is sent automaticly by the kernal,so I can't control it.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on which limit was hit.

If your memory limits (`-d`, `-v`) are hit, malloc (resp. the underlying `brk()/sbrk()`-call) will fail with `NULL` as return value. Your program will only segfault now, if this error condition isn't checked. You could check for an access *near* address 0 (struct member access) and then try to guess, if it is an unchecked malloc access. If you know, that you do not do malloc checks anywhere, you could also write a wrapper with an `assert(ret != NULL);` or similar.

If the stack limit (`-s`) is reached, the situation is different; A process simply accesses memory in the vincity of the stack and the operation system automatically enlarges the stack; or it doesn't, if the limit is hit. You can identify this by looking at the address, which caused the fault (in the `siginfo_t` structure of your handler), and checking, if it is near your stack.

All other ulimits shouldn't generate segfaults.

Comment: Considering that Linux is generally happy to overcommit memory, and let applications allocate more than is available, will imposing limits stop that overcommit? If not then `malloc` (et. al.) will never return `NULL` and the problem will be known first when the application attempt to use unavailable pages which will indeed lead to a crash.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude if you impose memory limits, these are usually set to a value below the available physical memory. You are correct, if the memory is _still_ overcommitted before the limits are reached, it might crash. However, this will not be a SEGV, but the OOM killer will kick in

Comment: @SomeProgrammerDude - It may be a good idea to setup a Solaris test rig since Solaris does not do the Linux overcommit virtual memory thing. I can barely get Solaris to run Sun's C++ compiler without crashing on large header or source files (and without limits). I've wasted hours trying to configure my test machines.

Comment: Thanks very much,but I can't understand the answer.I fork a subprocess in C,and use setrlimit interface to limit the resources of subprocess,then check it in the parent process.